# Type Mismatch Error In Excel VBA With "WITH"

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I am attempting to select a worksheet by name from an Add-In that is loaded in my workbook.  My code iterates up to the line of `With worksheets(ws1)` then it throws a

> Type mismatch error

What would be the correct way to perform actions on that worksheet and use the `with` feature?

```
Dim ws2 As Worksheet, ws1 As Worksheet
Dim aData

Set ws2 = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tastatas")

With Worksheets(ws1)
aData = .Range("a1").CurrentRegion
End With
```

Comment: `ws1` is a `Worksheet`.  You don't need to (can't) pass it to `Worksheets` as an index.  Just use `With ws1`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> With Worksheets(ws1)
> ```

When you do `Worksheets(ws1)`, you're actually calling `Application.Workbooks.Item` (the default property of the `Excel.Worksheets` *collection class*.

The `Item` property of a collection class is parameterized - it needs a *key* to retrieve an `Object` reference. So you need a *key*.

A `VBA.Collection` is keyed with a `String`. The `Item` property of the `Excel.Worksheets` collection class takes a `Variant` - this means at compile-time, *anything you give it will work*. The problem happens at run-time, when the `Variant` value is used to retrieve the `Object` associated with the *key* you gave it.

You can do `Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)` with any `Long` (or `Integer`) to retrieve the item by *index*.

You can do `Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")` with any `String` to retrieve the item by *name*.

And that's all. A string or a number.

`Dim ws2 As Worksheet, ws1 As Worksheet`

Beats my why you'd have `ws2` before `ws1`, but anyway `ws1` is a `Worksheet` object reference, not a `String`, not a `Long`.

So your code compiles because you're passing that reference to a `Variant` parameter, and blows up at run-time with a *type mismatch* error, because the type you supplied (`Worksheet`) *mismatches* the type that was expected (a `String`, or any integer numeric type).

---

The `With` block could very well hold that reference for you - which spares you the variable declaration:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tastatas")
    aData = .Range("A1").Value
End With
```

Notice the explicit `.Value` in the right-hand side of the assignment: it's still there if you leave it out, only it's *implicit*. That's because the `Range` class has a *default property* that points to its `Value`, which is a `Variant` that can contain a string, a date, a number, an error value... reading the value into a `Variant` is a very good idea: it spares you from another *type mismatch* error if the cell you're reading contains a `#REF!` or any other cell erorr value.

But because of the implicit default value, the only thing that can tell us whether `aData` is a value or a reference, is the assignment itself:

```
[Let] aData = .Range("A1") ' value assignment: aData is the cell's value.
Set aData = .Range("A1")   ' reference assignment: aData is a Range object.
```

Things are clearer with *explicit* code:

```
aData = .Range("A1").Value
Set aData = .Range("A1")
```